# How to read multiple keyboard inputs from the user at the same time?

Tags: assembly, input, x86, tasm

I am building pong and I want to get input from two users to move the rackets but when I am using int 16h ah1 (and ah0 to detect if a key was pressed wt all) it move one character at a time.

I found some solutions but becuase I am not a native engilsh speaker I couldn't understand them.

Comment: for games you are looking for make and break.

Answer (score 1):

[Int 16/AH=01h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1755.htm) is used to *check* for a keystroke.
While [Int 16/AH=00h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-1754.htm) is used to *get* the keystroke.

Note that you got them the other way around.

---

Here a very simple program that polls for keystrokes *A*, *D* and *Q*.
*A* increments player 1 blue character on row 1.
*D* increments player 2 red character on row 2.
*Q* quits the program.

If you press *A* and *D* together, both characters get incremented.

It uses a simple [Lookup table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table) to dispatch a key to its handler in order to avoid [Spaghetti code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code) when the program has a lot of functions.
Use the dispatching method that more suits your needs, giving a general efficient solution is out of the scope of this question.

```
BITS 16
ORG 100h

 mov ax, 0003h
 int 10h                            ;Set a known screen mode

 mov ax, 0b800h
 mov es, ax                         ;Set ES to access textual video buffer


 ;Write two 'A's (Blue and red)

 mov WORD [es:0000h], 0941h
 mov WORD [es:160], 0c41h

 ;We need BH zero for later
 xor bx, bx

_poll_key:

 ;CHECK FOR A KEY

 mov ah, 01h
 int 16h
jz _poll_key

 ;REMOVE THE KEY FROM THE BUFFER

 xor ah, ah
 int 16h

 mov bl, al
 call dispatch_key
jmp _poll_key



;
; D I S P A T C H E R
;

;BX = Key to dispatch
dispatch_key:
 push bx


 sub bx, 'a'
 jb _dk_end

 cmp bx, 26
 jae _dk_end


 shl bx, 1
 mov bx, WORD [dispatch_table + bx]

 test bx, bx
 jz _dk_end


 call bx

_dk_end:
 pop bx
 ret

dispatch_table:
        ;A
        dw _key_a
        ;B
        dw 0
        ;C
        dw 0
        ;D
        dw _key_d
        ;E
        dw 0
        ;F
        dw 0
        ;G
        dw 0
        ;H
        dw 0
        ;I
        dw 0
        ;J
        dw 0
        ;K
        dw 0
        ;L
        dw 0
        ;M
        dw 0
        ;N
        dw 0
        ;O
        dw 0
        ;P
        dw 0
        ;Q
        dw _key_q
        ;R
        dw 0
        ;S
        dw 0
        ;T
        dw 0
        ;U
        dw 0
        ;V
        dw 0
        ;W
        dw 0
        ;X
        dw 0
        ;Y
        dw 0
        ;Z
        dw 0

;
; K E Y   H A N D L E R S
;

;EXIT

_key_q:
 mov ax, 4c00h
 int 21h

;INCREMENT PLAYER 2 LETTER

_key_d:
 inc BYTE [es:160]
 ret

;INCREMENT PLAYER 1 LETTER

_key_a:
 inc BYTE [es:0000h]
 ret
```

Code is for NASM, to produce a COM file.

Comment: JFYI: the PC keyboards are notoriously known for being unable to handle some multi-combinations, sometimes already one player may hit particular combination which doesn't work (curiously enough the same model from same manufacturer did often have different ways how to "saturate" it), but especially with two players playing some fighting game this became real issue. The "pong" should be fine (4 keys in total?).